# Center text horizontally in fixed div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center four `h4` tags within their respective `fixed` divs (all with `width: 100%` to keep their `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` spanned across the whole browser width).

I've tried many combinations of CSS tags but haven't been able to sort it out.

Working draft: http://parkerrichard.com/new/art.html

HTML:

```
<!-- row 1: body -->
<div class="container thumb-page">
    <div class="row thumb-col mb">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fix"><h4 class="hidden-xs">PAINTING</h4></div>
            <h4 class="centered hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">PAINTING</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fix"><h4 class="hidden-xs">DRAWING</h4></div>
            <h4 class="centered hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm mt-sm">DRAWING</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fix"><h4 class="hidden-xs">DIGITAL</h4></div>
            <h4 class="centered hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm mt-sm">DIGITAL</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fix"><h4 class="hidden-xs">VIDEO</h4></div>
            <h4 class="centered hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm mt-sm">VIDEO</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Thumbnail section */

.thumb-col .fix {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.thumb-col h4 {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.thumb-col .fix h4 {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.thumb-col div a img {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need those titles to be positioned as `fixed`? If not, try changing from `class="fix"` to `class="text-center"`.

Comment: i do, so when the page scrolls down the viewer knows which category each column of images goes with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you make fixed position per header. Try to move all headers to new `.conatainer` above `.thumb-page` and add `position: relative` to this container row. Also keep same grid structure as you have for images and of course use `text-align: center` to each header text.

Edid:
Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyc2b2rg/1/)

Comment: that very nearly works - now the header columns are a bit more wide than the image columns so the text isn't quite perfectly centered above the column - any idea how to fix this? draft: http://parkerrichard.com/new/art.html

Comment: Yes, there should be couple more things as I found out playing around with fiddle. So keep header conteiner as relative and move fixed positioning to its row. Check fiddle if this is what you need.

Comment: I figured out a work-around: stuck the new header within it's own container with `position: fixed` into the row containing all the the image columns, above those columns. thank you for all your help sir

Answer (score 0):

Remove position: fixed; and add text-align: center; to align the text

```
.thumb-col .fix {
  position: fixed; - /* delete this */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; /* Add This */
```

Comment: this would work except I need the `div` `h4`'s to stay fixed in place at the top of the page